# How can I generate a random image using random function for infinite time?

Tags: c#, image, random

I am writing a code that generates a **bitmap image** using random pixels. I want to play this randomly generated images one after each other on the display like a **movie clip**.

I basically need a loop that goes thought my function every time and generates a new image and then display it to my image box and repeat this process **infinite time**.

```
While (true)
{
    foreach (Point p in blackPixels)
    {
       if (r.NextDouble() < 0.20)
       {
           bmp.SetPixel(p.X, p.Y, Color.Black);
       }
       else
       {
           bmp.SetPixel(p.X, p.Y, Color.White);
       }
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

My problem is I have put the whole code in to the “While (true)” but it crashed the programme!

Can anyone tell me the right way of playing with the code that works fine for every frame and can display every frame successive?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashed the programme"? Was there any exception that caused the application to terminate? If it just *froze* and didn't allow any input, please review your code and tell us in what part of the loop you expect any input to be processed while the loop is running.

Comment: yeap, basically it does not show anything and just stopped working

Comment: So - while your `while (true)` loop is running, where (in what line(s)) of your code do you expect the application to process any user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following instead:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 16);
timer.Tick += delegate
{
    timer.Stop();
    // your foreach code here
    foreach (Point p in blackPixels)
        ...
    timer.Start();
};
timer.Start();
```

It should update the picture every 16 seconds without blocking the GUI thread.

For the sake of accuracy, make sure that you stop the timer with `timer.Stop` before closing the form.

Comment: @user3266873 The code is executed with 16 seconds interval till the timer is stopped. If you want to do it `n` times only, you can add a counter and increase it within the delegate. When it exceeds the limit, you do not start the timer again.

Comment: thank you for your comment; could you please explain what are the (0, 0, 16)values? and how can i play the frames continually (with no delay)?

Comment: @user3266873 These are hours, minutes and seconds of `TimeSpan`, respectively. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: its giving me reference error for"DispatcherTimer"! should i add any library to my project?

Comment: I assume that you use WPF. Maybe you need to add `using System.Windows.Threading;` to use `DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: AlexD, could you please advice me on your code how can i remove the delays (no delay at all) or making some millisecond delay in my code? as this code gets the minimum 1 second as input.

Comment: @CowBoy You can use `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)` to specify `1` millisecond. But it is likely that slowness is caused by `foreach/SetPixel` loop, not by the timer. Try `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to see if it is the case.